# assign data from one table to a specific table (group)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a classrooms in schools and when I click on a certain classroom, I want to add students into it but my actual code is doing something stupid. It adds a student but i can see  the student in all classrooms, not just in the one that i added him into. So when Im in classroom number 1, I see a form in there, I can add a student there, ... see how it works here:

here is the code: http://www.xxxx.xx/projekt/

here is my code in file trieda.php

```
    <table align="center"><tr><td>
<form action="vlozit2.php" method="post">
  Meno: <input type="text" name="meno" placeholder="Janko" maxlength="15" required>
  Priezvisko: <input type="text" name="priezvisko" placeholder="Hruška" maxlength="20" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="id_triedy" value="<?= $trieda['id_triedy'] ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pridať študenta do triedy">
</form>
</td></tr></table>


<?php 
$result = mysqli_query($prip,"SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY meno");

while($student = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<br /><table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' class='tabulka1' align='center'><tr>";
    echo "<td width='200'><a href='student.php?id_triedy=".$trieda['id_triedy']."".id_student=".$student['id_student']."'>".$student['meno']." ".$student['priezvisko']."</a></td>";
    ?>
  <td width='300px' align='right' bgcolor="#fbfbfb"><a href="zmazat_studenta.php?id_student=<? echo $student['id_student']; ?>">Zmazať</a></td>
  </tr></table>
<?php 
  }
?>
```

here is vlozit2.php (a code that works for the form to add a student)

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    //meno a priezvisko
    $student = $_POST['meno'];
    $student = $_POST['priezvisko'];
    $trieda = $_POST['id_triedy'];


    //connect to the database
    include 'config.php';

    //insert results from the form input
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student (meno, priezvisko, id_triedy) VALUES('$_POST[meno]', '$_POST[priezvisko]', '$_POST[id_triedy]')";


        $add = "<table align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td> Študent bol úspešne pridaný do triedy. </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href='./trieda.php'><strong>Späť</strong></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>";
        $not_add = "<table align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td> Študent s týmto menom a priezviskom už je v tejto triede. </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href='./trieda.php'><strong>Späť</strong></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>";

        if (mysqli_query($prip, $sql)) {
            echo $add;
        }else{
            echo $not_add;
            }


    mysqli_close($prip);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your part of code with these snipets:

1) in trieda.php

```
<form action="vlozit2.php?id_triedy=<?php echo $_GET["id_triedy"];?>" method="post">
Meno: <input type="text" name="meno" placeholder="Janko" maxlength="15" required>
Priezvisko: <input type="text" name="priezvisko" placeholder="Hruška" maxlength="20" required>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pridať študenta do triedy">
</form>
```

2) in vlozit2.php

```
$student = $_POST['meno'];
$priezvisko = $_POST['priezvisko'];
$id_trieda = $_GET['id_triedy'];
```

and

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (meno, priezvisko, id_triedy) VALUES( '{$student}', '{$priezvisko}', {$id_trieda} )";
```

Hopefully you store your id_trieda as INT type.

Comment: then I suggest you echo your $sql statement before querying it, so that you see what you are sending to the db. Then post here the result pls.

Comment: now its working as you may see on the website, but it doesnt show students only in their classroom even though they have the ID of the classroom they were created in.

Comment: Then the listing of students for each classroom is faulty, try this query instead: $result = mysqli_query($prip,"SELECT * FROM student WHERE id_triedy ={$id_trieda} ORDER BY meno"); ... You have to replace  column name id_triedy with what you have as a foreign key for your table trieda.

Comment: it was giving me a warning but i changed your code a little and now its working perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `vlozit2.php` file is nothing about inserting of class id. So put

```
<input type="hidden" name="classId" value="<?= $trieda['id'] ?>" />
```

to your form and in `vlozit2.php` get this value from `$_POST['classId']` and insert it with other students data or anywhere you want to have it.

Comment: I edited my code but it doesnt work, check it, my post is updated... it shows the $not_add condition. ..

Comment: Do you have data table with proper structure? Did you receive the class id? Did you try to echo it? Is id well rendered in source of page?